# Why do Windows Updates all have a name like KB1234567?

Tags: windows-update

Why do Windows Updates all have a name like `KB1234567`? Is this because they all are referenced in their **K**nowledge **B**ase?

Comment: Self-answering question ftw.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is the knowledge base number... so you can quickly find the article about the update and what it fixes in the knowledge base.